# MEAN STACK variable comparison

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack, mean

```
Specimen.find( { filter_fin : filter_spec },
    {
        // Get only the taxonomy stuff
        "taxonomy.phylum": 1,
        "taxonomy.class": 1,
        "taxonomy.order": 1,
        "taxonomy.family": 1,
        "taxonomy.genus": 1,
        "taxonomy.species": 1,
        "common_name": 1,
        "last_edit": 1
    },
```

Hi above is my code, and my problem is that, Specimen.find( { "taxonomy.class": filter_spec }, it works. But when put the text ("taxonomy.class", etc.) in a variable, it doesn't work anymore. If I can't make this work, it will be very inefficient as I have to make it handle several cases.

Comment: How are you calling it when you use the variable, can you edit your question to include that part?

Comment: @chridam Specimen.find( { filter_fin : filter_spec },

that's exactly how I try to use it with the variable (filter_fin)

Comment: Can you please edit your question and not in the comments with this additional info?

Comment: @chridam it's not even additional, it was already there if you read it well

Comment: Ah, I finally get what you are saying Paul, my apologies :) An answer is on its way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the object property in a variable, then you need to use the **[square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)** to construct the field object as follows:

```
var query = { },
    projection = {
        // Get only the taxonomy stuff
        "taxonomy.phylum": 1,
        "taxonomy.class": 1,
        "taxonomy.order": 1,
        "taxonomy.family": 1,
        "taxonomy.genus": 1,
        "taxonomy.species": 1,
        "common_name": 1,
        "last_edit": 1
    };

query[filter_fin] = filter_spec;
Specimen.find(query, projection, callback);
```

Or using [**computed property names (ES6)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):

```
var query = { 
        [filter_fin]: filter_spec
    },
    projection = {
        // Get only the taxonomy stuff
        "taxonomy.phylum": 1,
        "taxonomy.class": 1,
        "taxonomy.order": 1,
        "taxonomy.family": 1,
        "taxonomy.genus": 1,
        "taxonomy.species": 1,
        "common_name": 1,
        "last_edit": 1
    };

Specimen.find(query, projection, callback);
```